# Is this a valid use of NULL foreign keys?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

Consider this very small contrived subset of my schema:

```
SensorType1
ID : PK

SensorType2
ID : PK

Reading
Timestamp
Value
SensorType1_ID FK -> SensorType1
SensorType2_ID FK -> SensorType2
```

Some readings are for SensorType1, some are for SensorType2.  I would probably add a constraint to ensure exclusively one of those FK's is always pointing somewhere.

I've read a lot in the past about NULL FK's being very bad design, but I've been wrestling with my schema for days (see previous posts) and no matter which way I twist and turn it, I either end up with a NULL-able FK somewhere, or I have to duplicate my reading table (and it's dependants) for every sensor type I have (3).

The above just seems to solve the problem nicely, but it leaves a not-so-nice taste in my mouth, for some reason.  It is the ONE place in my entire schema where I allow NULL fields.

I thought a bit of peer review would help me accept it before I move on.

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't `SensorType` a field in a single `Sensors` table, rather than a split between two tables?  Are the fields in each table different?

Comment: The type of sensor is not just a name in this case.  I'll perhaps post up a diagram of the schema once I've finished working on it as I'd be interested in constructive comments.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Here is the schema so far: 
http://thejunkroom.co.uk/~marks/MonitoringModelDraft1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with doing it like:

```
Sensor
  ID: PK
  ... common sensor fields ...

SensorType1
  ID: FK(Sensor)
  ... specifics ...

SensorType2
  ID: FK(Sensor)
  ... specifics ...

Reading
  ID: PK
  Sensor: FK(Sensor)
  Timestamp: DateTime
  Value: whatever
```

Comment: What stops a row in SensorType1 and SensorType2 both accidently pointing to the same Sensor?  The database would not catch that integrity error.

Comment: Seriously, if there's a way to stop that happening then I'll use it.  It's what I originally had, but it was too easy for the database to get in a mess without something to catch the data integrity error.

Comment: @marksim: you may want to add some constraints and it will work perfectly. The way to do is: add two fields to Sensor (isType1, isType2), they must be exclusive (a check constraint will do it) and you need constraints like if isType_ is not null then sensortype_ of the same id must exist.

Comment: The nest way I know to stop the integrity error is to have a trigger on the two sensortype tables that will not allow inserting if the sensor ID is in the other table.

Comment: You can ensure the sensor can only be of one type like this:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/01/08/Distributed-Keys-and-Disjoint-Subtypes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First PK's as just "ID" mean they have to change names constantly throughout the model. It makes following the RI difficult. I know some people like that. I hate it because it prevents an automated approach to finding columns.

I do things like this

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE Column_Name = :1;
```

If you need to "role play" have the same FK twice in a table then

```
LIKE '%' || :1 should work.
```

But you're changing col names even when not forced to. ID becomes Location_ID and then becomes LoggingLocation_ID for no technical reason

I'm assuming this isn't a physical model. If it is, why are you vertically partitioning LiveMonitoringLocation and HandProbingLocation? Is it just to avoid a nullable column? If so you're utility function is all messed up. Nullable columns are fine... adding a new table to avoid a nullable column is like driving from NYC to Cleveland to Boston in order to avoid any red lights.